# Jquery JqGrid data source url format

Tags: php, jquery, url, jqgrid

I have an html page with a jqgrid.
These hqgrid retreve data in json from a php script.
jQgrid retrieve data by default requesting this url:

```
http://localhost/projects/gestionalePreventivi/retrieve/imprese/?_search=false&nd=1311285005780&rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc
```

but I would this url modified in this mode:

```
http://localhost/projects/gestionalePreventivi/retrieve/imprese/false/1311285005780/10/1/id/desc
```

This is a little part of my code:

```
jQuery("#tabImprese").jqGrid({
                url:$myurl,
                datatype: "json",
                height: 150,
                .............
  });
```

How can I do it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/

Comment: I want to modify jqgrid url composition like in the message. I have already done in my project url rewriting and I need that jqgrid change its url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the usage of `url` in the form in which you as describe is a good idea. The way seems me not good from the architecture point of view.

Nevertheless from the technical side the dynamic modification of the `url` is do possible. One can use [beforeRequest](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event like the following:

```
beforeRequest: function() {
    var p = this.p, pd = p.postData;
    p.url = '/base/' + pd.rows + '/' + pd.page + '/' +
            encodeURIComponent(pd.sidx) + '/' + pd.sord;
    p.postData = {};
}
```

In the way the URL used will be like you as need: see the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleUrlModification.htm). Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for example you can verify which URL will be used.